# Istio Sidecar Injection failed

Tags: kubernetes

I have successfully installed istio in my k8 cluster, post that i followed GitHub ULR https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/samples/bookinfo/platform/kube/bookinfo.yaml  to deploy the bookinfo application.

After the deployment my bookinfo deployment pod is not available in my test ns.

Please find the below istio-system name spaces

```
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
grafana-784c89f4cf-cxpcz                1/1     Running   0          15d
istio-egressgateway-bd477794-qv7n8      1/1     Running   0          15d
istio-ingressgateway-79df7c789f-qlqcf   1/1     Running   0          15d
istiod-6dc55bbdd-t5klg                  1/1     Running   0          15d
jaeger-7f78b6fb65-xhz8j                 1/1     Running   0          15d
kiali-dc84967d9-99lwv                   1/1     Running   0          15d
prometheus-7bfddb8dbf-nd4gn             2/2     Running   0          15d
```

bookinfo deployment

```
root@master:~/istio-session# kubectl get pod,deployment,rs
NAME                             READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/details-v1       0/1     0            0           62m
deployment.apps/productpage-v1   0/1     0            0           62m
deployment.apps/ratings-v1       0/1     0            0           62m
deployment.apps/reviews-v1       0/1     0            0           62m
deployment.apps/reviews-v2       0/1     0            0           62m
deployment.apps/reviews-v3       0/1     0            0           62m

NAME                                        DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/details-v1-79f774bdb9       1         0         0       62m
replicaset.apps/productpage-v1-6b746f74dc   1         0         0       62m
replicaset.apps/ratings-v1-b6994bb9         1         0         0       62m
replicaset.apps/reviews-v1-545db77b95       1         0         0       62m
replicaset.apps/reviews-v2-7bf8c9648f       1         0         0       62m
replicaset.apps/reviews-v3-84779c7bbc       1         0         0       62m
```

Here the events from k8

```
stio.io": Post "https://istiod.istio-system.svc:443/inject?timeout=30s": context deadline exceeded
45m         Warning   FailedCreate        replicaset/reviews-v3-84779c7bbc       Error creating: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "sidecar-injector.istio.io": Post "https://istiod.istio-system.svc:443/inject?timeout=30s": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
42m         Warning   FailedCreate        replicaset/reviews-v3-84779c7bbc       Error creating: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "sidecar-injector.istio.io": Post "https://istiod.istio-system.svc:443/inject?timeout=30s": dial tcp 10.102.193.69:443: i/o timeout
52m         Normal    ScalingReplicaSet   deployment/reviews-v3                  Scaled up replica set reviews-v3-84779c7bbc
```

Note: required port already opened 10250,tcp:443,tcp:15017

Could you please some one help me on this

Comment: This could be an issue how your Kubernetes cluster was configured and if Istio is working properly. Please add the information about how you've created the cluster and how exactly you've installed Istio. To use the elimination method and limit the potential causes I'd check if you can deploy a simple `nginx` pod in default namespace and see if it works. Also, does the communication in your cluster is working correctly?

Comment: Yes my cluster is working correctly i deployed full micro service application